# NModBus WriteMuitipleRegister Exception

Tags: c#, modbus-tcp

I'm working in a project with read/write a device through Modbus TCP (device can establish a virtual server) using NModBus. I'm using a timer to read, this works fine (`ReadHoldingRegisters`) but, when I try write to device with `WriteMultipleRegister`, the program shows `System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection`, but data can write in, here is the code i use.

```
public class ModbusController {
  private TcpClient tcpClient;
  private IModbusMaster modbusMaster;

  public ModbusController(string ipAddress, int port) {
    tcpClient = new TcpClient(ipAddress, port);
    var factory = new ModbusFactory();
    modbusMaster = factory.CreateMaster(tcpClient);

  }

  public async Task WriteData(ushort startAddress, ushort[] data) {
    await modbusMaster.WriteMultipleRegistersAsync(1, startAddress, data);
  }
}

ModbusController controller;

private async Task < bool > WriteToRegister() {
  ushort value = ushort.Parse(txtValue.Text);
  ushort address = (ushort) int.Parse(txtRegister.Text);

  ushort[] data = [value];

  Debug.WriteLine(value);

  try {
    controller = new ModbusController("172.16.100.106", 502);
    await controller.WriteData(address, data);
    return true;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    return false;
  }
}

private async void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  bool writeResult = await WriteToRegister();
}
```

At first, I'm using `WriteSingleRegister` for write in, but it's odd that it only change one bit/send, in my opinion, for example, if i send value 7 to register `100`, it's should show `0111` (binary) on address `100` right away, but instead it shows `0001`, i need to send value 7 again get `0011`, and send again get `0111`, shouldn't it became the value what I've send at first time?

but in this situation, program works fine with no exception, I'm also use Modbus Poll tool to check, read/write multiple register works fine, but `writesingleregister` perform the same, change one bit/send. so i change to use `WriteMultipleRegister`, and then the exception occurred. is that could be some step I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please post the full Stack Trace of the Exception when it happens? Might help us figure out at what point in the writing process it fails.

Comment: It's difficult to help without knowledge of the device you are writing to. It's quite possible that the device is updating the register value immediately following a write (and might not support command `16`). Please show us the Modbus Poll command lines used and output.